# How can I progress "The Molecular level" quest with the Brotherhood of Steel?

Tags: fallout-4

I just got the schematic for the molecular relay and want to build this with the Brotherhood of Steel but every time I talk to Danse he says the repeating lines like "fix armor in garage, the sooner Halen has transmitter installed the better, dealing with pests, ask around to help" or he just says "I'm busy".

I am unsure of how to proceed. I am an initiate and I have been doing the other quests for Rhys and Halen nonstop but seemingly no progression. What am I missing?

Comment: You will have to progress in the main story for this to happen. Danse is not glitched in this case, he just doesn't care basically haha. You will know when you can move on.

Answer (score 3):

The side quests you've been completing for Rhys and Halen are infinitely repeatable side quests and do not directly progress the main story of the game. The Brotherhood of Steel quests leading up to the Molecular Level [are as follows](http://www.polygon.com/fallout-4/2015/11/9/9696326/brotherhood-steel-quests):

- Fire Support: Join the shootout at the Cambridge Police Station.
- Call to Arms: Follow Paladin Danse to ArcJet Systems.
- Semper Invicta: Accept your first quests as an official member of the Brotherhood of Steel.
- Shadow of Steel: Hitch a ride on an airship to get a promotion.
- Tour of Duty: It's orientation day at the Prydwen.
- Show No Mercy: It's time to hunt mutants.

Since you're already doing the side quests for Rhys and Halen you've likely already completed at least Fire Support and Call to Arms and if Danse is not talking to you then you're probably on Shadow of Steel.

For the Shadow of Steel mission you need to tune your Pip boy into the military frequency named AF95, which will then update your Pip boy with instructions to meet up with Paladin Danse on the roof of the Cambridge police station, to fly off to the Prydwen.

Comment: Should probably point out that there are main story quests that need to be done between some of those BoS quests. Need to do Reunions (most of it) before Shadow of Steel can start, and need to do The Glowing Sea and Hunter/Hunted before The Molecular Level.